# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' (a few frames into program)

Tags: python, pygame

So as my first project in python outside of Code Academy, I decided to make a basic molecular dynamics simulator on pygame. It works fine for a while, but as soon as electrons start to move too fast, and strip all the other electrons off their atoms, I get the TypeError in the title. I have no idea where this comes from, and only appears after the program has been running long enough for me to mess up all the physics.

Now I know that the error is telling me that I'm trying to pass a list somewhere I shouldn't, but I've looked over the program and can't figure out where. The error pops up in the bit that tells electrons how to orbit their atom `angle = findA(particles[el], particles[nuc]) + 0.001`, which is controlled by the block of code near the end that tells the program in which order to do physics, and the list of what each electron is meant to orbit is controlled by another point, and so on.

So I decided just to give you all the code.

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
sizeScreen = width, height = 1000, 700
sizeMenu = width, height = 652, 700


e = 1.6 * 10 ** -19
particles = {}
mx, my = 0, 0
selected = []

def findOrbital(el):
    for a in particles:
        if a != el and particles[a][4] != 'el':
            if findD(particles[el], particles[a]) < 5 * 10 ** -11 and PTI[particles[a][4]][7] > len(particles[a][5]):
                particles[a][5].append(el)
                particles[el][5].append(a)



def searcher(List, item):
    for a in List:
        if a == item:
            return True
    return False

def moveAtEls(el, nuc):
    angle = findA(particles[el], particles[nuc]) + 0.001
    particles[el][0] = particles[nuc][0] + 50 * math.cos(angle)
    particles[el][1] = particles[nuc][1] + 50 * math.sin(angle)


def check(each):
    if particles[each][0] < 175:
        particles[each][2] = -particles[each][2]
        particles[each][0] = 175
    elif particles[each][0] > 1000:
        particles[each][2] = -particles[each][2]
        particles[each][0] = 1000
    if particles[each][1] < 0:
        particles[each][3] = -particles[each][3]
        particles[each][1] = 0
    elif particles[each][1] > 700:
        particles[each][3] = -particles[each][3]
        particles[each][1] = 700
    if particles[each][4] == 'el':
        a = 'n'
        findOrbital(each)
        if a != 'n':
            particles[each][5].append(a)
            particles[a][5].append(each)


def findD(self, other):
    return math.hypot((self[0] - other[0]), (self[1] - other[1])) * 0.62 * 10 ** -12
def findA(self, other):
    return math.atan2((self[1] - other[1]), (self[0] - other[0]))


def move(self):
    for other in particles:
        if particles[other] != self and self[5] != particles[other] [5] and not searcher(self[5], other):
            D = findD(self, particles[other])
            if D == 0:
                self[5].append(other)
                particles[other][5].append(self)
                break
            angle = findA(self, particles[other])
            F = 8987550000 * (PTI[self[4]][4] * PTI[particles[other][4]][4] * e ** 2)/D ** 2
            a = int(F/PTI[self[4]][5])
            ax = a * math.cos(angle)
            ay = a * math.sin(angle)
            self[2] += ax/(10 ** 16)
            self[3] += ay/(10 ** 16)
    self[0] += self[2]/(10 ** 8)
    self[1] += self[3]/(10 ** 8)


pressed = ''
press = {'Katom':[2,148,2,32,0],'Knuc':[2,148,36,66,0],'Kel':[2,148,70,100,0]}

PTI = {'el':[0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 9.11 * 10 ** -31, pygame.image.load("electron.png"), 2],
'HNuc' : [185, 214, 8, 37, 1, 1.7 * 10 ** -27, pygame.image.load("nuc/HNuc.png"), 2, 1],
'HeNuc': [586, 613, 8, 37, 2, 6.6 * 10 ** -27, pygame.image.load("nuc/HeNuc.png"), 2, 2],
'LiNuc': [185, 214, 40, 69, 1, 1.16 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/LiNuc.png"), 8, 1],
'BeNuc': [216, 246, 40, 69, 2, 1.53 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/BeNuc.png"), 8, 2],
'BNuc' : [428, 457, 40, 69, 3, 1.84 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/BNuc.png"), 8, 3],
'CNuc' : [460, 489, 40, 69, 4, 2.04 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/CNuc.png"), 8, 4],
'NNuc' : [492, 520, 40, 69, 5, 2.38 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/NNuc.png"), 8, 5],
'ONuc' : [523, 551, 40, 69, 6, 2.72 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/ONuc.png"), 8, 6],
'FNuc' : [554, 583, 40, 69, 7, 3.23 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/FNuc.png"), 8, 7],
'NeNuc': [586, 613, 40, 69, 8, 3.43 * 10 ** -26, pygame.image.load("nuc/NeNuc.png"), 8, 8]}

menu = pygame.display.set_mode(sizeMenu)
screenColor = pygame.Color(255, 255, 220)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(sizeScreen)
edgeObj = pygame.image.load("edge.png")
addEl = [pygame.image.load('addElectron1.png'), pygame.image.load('addElectron2.png')]
addAtom = [pygame.image.load("addAtom1.png"), pygame.image.load("addAtom2.png"), pygame.image.load("atomTable.png")]
addNucleus = [pygame.image.load("addNuc1.png"), pygame.image.load("addNuc2.png"), pygame.image.load("NucTable.png")]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)

        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mx, my = event.pos

        mouseState = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if mouseState[0]:
            for key in press:
                if press[key][0] < mx <press[key][1] and press[key][2] < my < press[key][3]:
                    pressed = key
                    press[key][4] = 1

        if not mouseState[0] and pressed == 'Kel':
            particles[len(particles)] = [mx, my, 0, 0, 'el', []]
            pressed = ''
            press['Kel'][4] = 0

        if pressed != '':
            if not mouseState[0]:
                if press[pressed][0] < mx <press[pressed][1] and press[pressed][2] < my < press[pressed][3]:
                    press[pressed][4] = 2
                    pressed = ''

        if press['Knuc'][4] == 2 or press['Katom'][4] == 2:
            if  mouseState[0]:
                if 621 < mx < 651 and 2 < my < 14:
                    press['Knuc'][4] = 0
                    press['Katom'][4] = 0
                if press['Knuc'][4] == 2:
                    for nuc in PTI:
                        if PTI[nuc][0] < mx < PTI[nuc][1] and PTI[nuc][2] < my < PTI[nuc][3]:
                            press['Knuc'][4] = 0
                            selected.append(nuc)
                if press['Katom'][4] == 2:
                    for nuc in PTI:
                        if PTI[nuc][0] < mx < PTI[nuc][1] and PTI[nuc][2] < my < PTI[nuc][3]:
                            a = 0
                            selected.append(nuc)
                            while a < PTI[nuc][8]:
                                selected.append('el')
                                a += 1
                            press['Katom'][4] = 0
        if selected != []:
            if not mouseState[0]:
                a = len(particles)
                particles[a] = [mx, my, 0, 0, selected[0], [b for b in range(a+1, len(selected)-1)]]
                for item in selected:
                    if item != selected[0]:
                        particles[len(particles)] = [mx, my, 0, 0, item, [a]]
                selected = []


    for each in particles:
        check(each)
        move(particles[each])
        check(each)
        if len(particles[each][5]) > 0 and particles[each][4] == 'el':
            moveAtEls(each, particles[each][5][0])
        particles[each][5] = []

    screen.fill(screenColor)
    for a in particles:
        screen.blit(PTI[particles[a][4]][6], (particles[a][0] - 29, particles[a][1] - 31))
    menu.blit(edgeObj, (0, 0))
    menu.blit(addNucleus[press['Knuc'][4]], (2, 2))
    menu.blit(addAtom[press['Katom'][4]], (2, 2))
    menu.blit(addEl[press['Kel'][4]], (2, 2))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Sorry if I'm being a nuisance by posting all the code, but I'm a complete n00b and I'm surprised I got this far without help. I know the whole thing is untidy, but if you could help with the error I'd greatly appreciate it.

Next time I'll just stick to `print("Hello, World!")`

Comment: Put a try/except around the statement in findA.  Except the TypeError. In the except clause, print self, other and maybe type(self), type(other) or maybe just print locals() since it is a pretty straight forward function.  Re-raise the exception. You will be able to see if you are passing it what you think you are passing it.  If you are using windows/Idle, you can inspect the stack with the StackViewer option of the Debug menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I believe is happening is that when execute the line `angle = findA(particles[el], particles[nuc]) + 0.001`, either the `el` variable or the `nuc` variable is a list of some sort, rather then a single object.

This throws an error because `particles` is a dict, and you cannot have a list or any mutable type as a key in a dict.

So, given that this error does not execute immediately, I suspect that somewhere along the line, in a piece of code that is not immediately executed, you are accidentally passing in a `list` of some sort.

---

If you did mean to look things up in the `particles` dict by using a list as a key, then you should convert the list to a `tuple` first: tuples are like lists, but are immutable, and so can be hashed and used as a key of a dict.